# How to record images in SVG animations

Tags: javascript, svg

I have an animated SVG like this:

```css
image {
    animation: pulse 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.5)
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <image height="200" width="300" href="https://i.imgur.com/4AiXzf8.jpeg">
  </image>
</svg>
```

I wish to record a video of this animation (using JS not screen-recording software). I'm doing this by recording each frame of the SVG animation onto a canvas with this code ([JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bLq574ko/5/)):

```js
function addFrameToBuffer(canvas, svgElement) {
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
  const svgURL = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svgElement);
  const img = new Image();
  img.onload = () => {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    const frame = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height).data;
  };
  img.src = 'data:image/svg+xml; charset=utf8, ' + encodeURIComponent(svgURL);
}
```

The problem is that my code doesn't render images inside SVGs. They appear like this:

[image]

I managed to create a work-around, by first converting the images from using external hrefs, to base64 strings. The problem is that these base64 strings are so large that when the browser has to render multiple images it often hangs or lags while animating (especially when using anime.js).

Comment: I think a possible solution might be to use [Canvg](https://github.com/canvg/canvg) instead of `XMLSerializer()`, but I haven't been able to get it to work yet

Comment: You’ll probably have more success with an SVG document rather than an element. `data:` URLs expect full files; in the case of SVG, full documents. So: `const svgDocument = new Document(); svgDocument.append(svgElement); const svgURL = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svgDocument);`. You may have to prepend `svgURL` with `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>` as well.

Comment: Convert the image contents into a data URL.

Comment: @RobertLongson That... worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Convert the image contents into a data URL. – [Robert Longson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1038015/robert-longson) [Jan 12 at 7:51](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65678090#comment116125195_65678090)

The solution is convert the image into a [`data:` URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs). See the function `getDataUrlImage()`.

```js
let isRecordingStarted = false;
let isStoppedRecording = false;
const svgElement = document.querySelector('svg')
const canvas2d = document.querySelector('#background-canvas');

document.getElementById('btn-start-recording').onclick = async () => {
  // Make external url images work in the canvas
  const images = document.querySelectorAll('image');
  for (const img of images) {
    const dataUrl = await this.getDataUrlImage(img.href.baseVal);
    img.setAttribute('href', dataUrl);
  }

  isRecordingStarted = true;
  isStoppedRecording = false;
}

async function getDataUrlImage(href) {
  const blob = await fetch(href).then((r) => r.blob());
  return await new Promise((resolve) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
  });
}

function addFrameToBuffer(ctx) {
  const svgURL = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svgElement);
  const img = new Image();
  img.onload = () => {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas2d.width, canvas2d.height);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    const frame = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas2d.width, canvas2d.height).data;
  };
  img.src = 'data:image/svg+xml; charset=utf8, ' + encodeURIComponent(svgURL);
}

const looper = () => {
  if (!isRecordingStarted) {
    return setTimeout(looper, 500);
  }

  addFrameToBuffer(canvas2d.getContext('2d'));

  if (isStoppedRecording) {
    return;
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(looper);
};

looper();
```

```html
<button id="btn-start-recording">
  Record
</button>

<canvas id="background-canvas"></canvas>

<svg height="400" width="400">
  <image height="200" width="300" href="https://i.imgur.com/4AiXzf8.jpeg">
  </image>
  <image href="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/image) says:

> SVG files displayed with `<image>` are treated as an image: external resources aren't loaded, `:visited` styles aren't applied, and they cannot be interactive. To include dynamic SVG elements, try `<use>` with an external URL. To include SVG files and run scripts inside them, try `<object>` inside of `<foreignObject>`.

See specifically "external resources aren't loaded". I suspect this applies to all uses of an SVG as an image.

Comment: It seems MDN is talking about using an SVG in an `<image>`, while I'm talking about using an `<image>` in an `<svg>`. Also, there doesn't seem to be a solution in your answer

Comment: @ChickenSuop As I said, "I suspect this applies to all uses of an SVG as an image." As you've already discovered, converting the external image to an internal one (by converting it to bas64) is the only solution that still involves using `<image>`.